# Javascript MySQL Connection on HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm using node.js's node-mysql driver for MySQL. I wrote this scrap of code

```
    var mysql = require("mysql");
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : "localhost",
        user     : "root",
        password : "",
        database : "story"
    });
    function testQuery() {
        connection.query("INSERT INTO stories (TITLE, AUTHOR, STORY) VALUES        
        (\"hello\",\"goodbye\",\"sayonara\")", function(err,rows){
            if(err) throw err;
        }   )
        return;
    }
```

So when I run the code in the testQuery() function in the node.js command line and it works as expected inserting hello goodbye and sayonara into the mysql database. But when I place the script into a HTML page and have a button onclick run testQuery() I don't get any result.

Comment: running in the browser is not the same as running in Node.

Comment: `node-mysql` is a server-side component. The server is built on `node.js` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run Nodejs server code on the client, this will not work. Also this would mean you will become hacked instantly because your password is stored in encrypted, plain text and stored on the clients machine. Double no no. You must start a new node instance and serve this code from the server, not from the browser.